# Need to understand multiprocessing

Tags: python, multiprocessing

I am trying to apply multiprocessing to a code of mine. I will try to explain it as follows:

```
def convert_data(df):
    # A function to convert categorical/object datatypes to numerical format by performing OHE or vectorization.
    ...


def impute_data(df):
    # A function which imputes missing data using various methods.
    # Some models which are used for this are DecisionTree Classifier, Logistic Regression etc.
    # Uses the above convert_data() function on the training set.
    # Returns dataframe without any missing data
    ...

try:
    df = impute_data(df)
except Exception as e:
    print(e)
```

Now, inside the `impute_data()`, I try this:

```
def impute_data(df):
    ...
    X = df.drop([col], axis=1)
    data_chunks = np.array_split(X, 100)  # The data is having ~5 Million rows
    with Pool() as pool:
        res = pool.map(convert_data, data_chunks)
    X = pd.concat(res)
    ...
```

This results in an error:

```
RuntimeError: 
        An attempt has been made to start a new process before the
        current process has finished its bootstrapping phase.

        This probably means that you are not using fork to start your
        child processes and you have forgotten to use the proper idiom
        in the main module:

            if __name__ == '__main__':
                freeze_support()
                ...

        The "freeze_support()" line can be omitted if the program
        is not going to be frozen to produce an executable.
```

Now I know this is happening due to the fact that `Pool` should be used inside `if __name__ == "__main__"`, but I have to import this file in some other file for use. How should I proceed from here?

---

## EDIT

If I run the above code like this:

```
def impute_data(pool, df):
    ...
    X = df.drop([col], axis=1)
    data_chunks = np.array_split(X, 100)  # The data is having ~5 Million rows
    res = pool.map(convert_data, data_chunks)
    X = pd.concat(res)
    ...


if __name__ == "__main__":
    try:
        with Pool() as _pool:
            df = impute_data(_pool, df)
    except Exception as e:
        print(e)
```

Will this work? This is assuming that this current file is now the main file and not getting imported anywhere else.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The *other* file that is importing it needs to properly use the same guard. If it doesn't, it's inherently incompatible with `multiprocessing`. Change the "some other file" (the main module mentioned in the error) so it guards its script-like behaviors properly, there's no reasonable way to solve this portably (e.g. on Windows where `fork` is straight up unavailable) anywhere else.

Comment: I still have a doubt. I would still need to use `Pool` which is inside the `impute_data()` function. Will running the main file with `if __name__ == "__main__"` solve this issue?

Comment: I have made an edit to the original question. Please do share your thoughts on the change @ShadowRanger

Comment: The *only* requirement is that any code that leads to launching `Process`es, including indirectly via `Pool`s, will not *execute* except through a path guarded by `if __name__ == "__main__":`. If the path isn't guarded, the workers (which are launched by launching the same way as the main script, but with `__name__ == "__mp_main__"`, to ensure imports and class/function definitions are duplicated (in unguarded code) without running the "main script" behaviors (in guarded code) that would lead to trying to launch the `Process`/`Pool` *again* from the child processes.

Comment: @ARIJITSINGH: Nothing about your edit changes the answer; if the unguarded path of main script execution tries to launch a `Process`/`Pool`, your code is wrong. It doesn't matter if it does so in the main script or elsewhere, what matters is whether the code *can* execute through an unguarded code path (typically starting in main and branching out through the various imported functions and classes).

Comment: I am sorry if this might seem stupid, but if I define the function `impute_data` inside `if __name__ == "__main__"`, will that solve the issue?

Comment: @ARIJITSINGH: If you define it inside a guarded block, but call it from outside a guarded block, then all your workers will crash when they try to call an undefined function. Function definitions should not be guarded (though if they can only be called from guarded code, it's legal to guard the definition as well, just strange). You seem to want an answer other than "fix your main script", but that's the answer. Fix the main script. There is no reasonable solution to the problem that isn't "write the main script with proper guards"; your module can't fix the problem by itself.